# Extract float from price-formatted string using regex in jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

Reaching out to all the JS regex gurus out there. I am building a function that would remove $, white space, comma, [A-Z], [a-z] from string, leaving only float (if it exists within the string given) something like so:

```
var result = myFunction( 'USD $12, 345.95'); //result = 12345.95
var result = myFunction( 'ten dollars US' ); // result = false

function myFunction( weirdString ){

    // some code

}
```

I know I can go something like (forgive me if I'm wrong):

```
weirdString.replace(/[&$<>"'`=\/\s]|[A-Z]|[a-z]/g, '');
isNaN( weirdString ) ? return false : return weirdString;
```

But what is the right way?

Comment: No need to separate those square bracket character sets with alternators. You can just use ```[&$<>"'`=\/ A-Z]a-z]```. Also just use a literal space if that's all you're expecting. `\s` matches any whitespace character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of blacklisting every character you don't want to allow, you can kind of whitelist only the characters you need:

```
[^\d.]  // match anything that isn't a digit or period
```

The advantage of this is that you don't have to think of every possible character to reject. For example, if for whatever reason, the character `é` (e with an accent) appears in your string, the regex you were using will consider it as part of the floating point number, which you probably don't want.

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/g8zBRP/2

Answer (score 0):

So here's the function I came up with:

```
function extractFloatFromString( input ){

    var result = input.match( /[\d+.]/g );
    return result == null ? 0 : result.join('');

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7hq1dcwn/3/